# How to debug D3D12 _com_error Exception

Tags: exception, shader, hlsl, direct3d

I'm creating a dynamic upload heap, and uploading some data to it, and have zero issues or warnings. But as soon as I try to read index zero from the HLSL structured buffer (`float4 some_data = MyBuffer[0];`), I get a _com_error exception when I use `SwapChain->Present()`. If I remove the shader buffer access line, everything works as expected with no messages.

I'm assuming I'm making a mistake somewhere, and my upload heap is not reaching its target for whatever reason, which means my shader buffer is uninitialized. But this is just a random guess.

Here is the exception message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8A925CD29 in Kestarda.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x000000B714CFC7D0.
```

The exception is being thrown pretty deep in the call stack:

```
D3D12Core.dll!CDevice::CreateLayeredChild(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D12LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)    Unknown
D3D12Core.dll!CBridgeImpl<struct ID3D12LayeredDevice,struct ID3D12LayeredDevice,class CLayeredObject<class NDXGI::CDevice> >::CreateLayeredChild(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D12LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &,void * *) Unknown
d3d12SDKLayers.dll!NDebug::CDeviceChild<struct ID3D12CommandAllocator>::FinalConstruct(enum ED3D12DeviceChildType,struct SLayeredArgs const *,unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D12LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &)  Unknown
d3d12SDKLayers.dll!CLayeredObject<class NDebug::CCommandAllocator>::CreateInstance(struct NDebug::CCommandAllocator::TConstructorArgs const &,void *,void *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)  Unknown
d3d12SDKLayers.dll!NDebug::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D12LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
D3D12.dll!NOutermost::CDevice::CreateLayeredChild(unsigned int,void const *,unsigned __int64,struct ID3D12LayeredUseCounted *,struct _GUID const &,void * *)    Unknown
D3D12Core.dll!CDevice::CreateCommandAllocator(enum D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE,struct _GUID const &,void * *)   Unknown
d3d12SDKLayers.dll!NDebug::CDevice::CreateCommandAllocator(enum D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE,struct _GUID const &,void * *)  Unknown
dxgi.dll!CD3D12Device::InitCommandList(unsigned int,enum CD3D12Device::QueueType)   Unknown
dxgi.dll!CD3D12Device::CloseAndSubmitCommandList(unsigned int,enum CD3D12Device::QueueType) Unknown
dxgi.dll!CD3D12Device::PresentExtended(struct DXGI_PRESENTSURFACE const *,unsigned int,struct IDXGIResource *,void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int *) Unknown
dxgi.dll!CFlipPresentToDWM<CDXGISwapChainWrapper>::FlipPresentCore()    Unknown
dxgi.dll!CDXGISwapChain::FlipPresentToDWM() Unknown
dxgi.dll!CDXGISwapChain::PresentImplCore(struct SPresentArgsCore<struct CDXGISwapChainWrapper> const *,unsigned int,struct tagRECT const *,unsigned int,struct DXGI_SCROLL_RECT const *,struct IDXGIResource *,struct CDXGISwapChain::PresentResultActions &)   Unknown
dxgi.dll!CDXGISwapChain::PresentImpl()  Unknown
dxgi.dll!CDXGISwapChain::Present()  Unknown
>> Kestarda.exe!Diligent::SwapChainD3D12Impl::Present(unsigned int SyncInterval) Line 157   C++
Kestarda.exe!KGraphics::SceneShow(bool reset_on_fail) Line 646  C++
Kestarda.exe!KShell::FrameGraphicsEnd() Line 335    C++
Kestarda.exe!KShell::FrameGraphics() Line 362   C++
Kestarda.exe!KShell::FrameExecute() Line 136    C++
Kestarda.exe!MainFrame::LifeCycle::Execute() Line 627   C++
Kestarda.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * h_instance, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * command_line, int __formal) Line 107  C++
```

I've tried wrapping `Present()` with a `_com_error` catch, but it does nothing, both running in the debugger and out of it, I get no messages:

```
try
{
    // attempt to present the scene
    System.SwapChain->Present( ... );
}
catch(const _com_error &x)
{
    app_error( x.ErrorMessage() );
}
```

After the _com_error exception, if I continue on, I get a ton of other exceptions about accessing memory location 0x0, then it just shuts down.

Is there any way to debug an issue like this? D3D12 is clearly throwing an exception, but I can't seem to get any information about why?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/directx-12-programming-environment-set-up#debug-layer

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the debug layer, as far as I can tell. But it just prints "Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8A925CD29 in Kestarda.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00000029AE13C510." . Don't get me wrong, I appreciate knowing there is an exception, but it would be great if they included the actual error string with the message.